# Replace MultiLine with SingleLine in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, replace

I want to replace the following 3 lines:

```
this.CSType = typeof(DateTimeOffset?);
this.CSTypeString = "Target";
this.MappedCSType = SQLTypes.MappedCSType.NullableDateTimeOffset;
```

With this:

```
result = "Target";
```

So I try to use this regex:

Find: `:bthis.CSType = typeof(*);\n:bthis.CSTypeString = "{[^"]+}";\n:bthis.MappedCSType = SQLTypes.MappedCSType.*;`

Replace: `result = "\1";`

But there is an error: `Grouped expression is missing ')'.`

Is there any fault in my expression? what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem with your regex is that you do not have group defined. I suppose you tried to define group by using pair of `{[^"]+}` which is not syntactically correct. Groups are defined using round brackets `()`.  Also `typeof(*)` will not match `typeof(DateTimeOffset?)`.

You can try following xpath

```
this.CSType = typeof\(.*\);\nthis.CSTypeString = "([^"]+)";\nthis.MappedCSType = SQLTypes.MappedCSType.*
```

Notice pair of round brackets `([^"]+)`. This group i.e group 1 will match `Target` string. You can validate this xpath at http://regexpal.com

Hope this helps